# Displaying Favorite Contact In ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to display favorited contact in `ListView` using image. I was able to display in Alphabetical order, but displaying the `Favourite ICON` first for favourited items hasn't been easy. This is my code

```
 mProjection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID
    };

    final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            mProjection,
            null,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"
    );
    ContactListAdapter listAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, mProjection);
    list = getListView();
    list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

And My Adapter Class

```
 public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCursor;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String[] mProjection;

// State of the row that needs to show separator
private static final int SECTIONED_STATE = 1;
// State of the row that need not show separator
private static final int REGULAR_STATE = 2;
// Cache row states based on positions
private int[] mRowStates;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, String[] projection){
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = cursor;
    mRowStates = new int[getCount()];
    mProjection = projection;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    boolean showSeparator = false;

    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);

    TextView cntName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cntName);
    TextView cntNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cntNumber);

    String name = mCursor.getString( mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[0]) );
    String number = mCursor.getString( mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[1]) );
    int idCol = mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[2]);
    long id = mCursor.getLong(idCol);

    cntName.setText(name);
    cntNumber.setText(number);

    // Show separator ?
    switch (mRowStates[position]) {

        case SECTIONED_STATE:
            showSeparator = true;
            break;

        case REGULAR_STATE:
            showSeparator = false;
            break;

        default:

            if (position == 0) {
                showSeparator = true;
            }
            else {
                mCursor.moveToPosition(position - 1);

                String previousName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mProjection[0]));
                char[] previousNameArray = previousName.toCharArray();
                char[] nameArray = name.toCharArray();

                if (nameArray[0] != previousNameArray[0]) {
                    showSeparator = true;
                }

                mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            }

            // Cache it for later
            mRowStates[position] = showSeparator ? SECTIONED_STATE : REGULAR_STATE;

            break;
    }

    TextView separatorView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.acronym);
    TextView separatorView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.acronym1);
    ImageView croppedProfile = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.croppedProfile);
    InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id));
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    if (bitmap == null){
        croppedProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_draw);
    } else {
        croppedProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    if (showSeparator) {
        separatorView.setText(name.toCharArray(), 0, 1);
        //separatorView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        separatorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        separatorView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        //separatorView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        //croppedProfile
        separatorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        separatorView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(80, 0, 0, 0);
        margLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

Comment: I know how to get the starred contacts. But displaying in a form whereby you see favorite first on the list with the favorite icon and then show next letters on your segmented ListView